# JPA: How to represent JoinTable and composite key of a JoinTable?

Tags: mysql, jpa, many-to-many, join

Let's say I have a webapp where users can follow other users.

In my database, I have a `User` table, and a `Following` table.

The `Following` table just has two values: a followingUserId and a followedUserId.

In Java, I have a User class. Most tutorials I see involve one object containing a set of objects it's related to. So many tutorials can describe how to have Users have a set of users following that user, and a set of users followed by a user. But that would require a lot of memory.

I'm thinking of an alternate structure where a User object has no info about following. Instead, there is a Following object that looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Following")
public class Following {
    RegisteredUser follower;
    RegisteredUser followed;
}
```

and corresponds to the join table. When I want to get all the followers of a user, I can do a query for all Following objects with that user as the follower.

My issues are:

1. The Followers Table has a composite key of each of the two userids. How can I use annotations to represent that composite key? The @Id annotation denotes a single variable as the key
2. How can I do such a query?

If it's relevant, I am using MySQL as the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using JPA > 2.0, you can mark relationships as your ID:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Following")
@IdClass(FollowingId.class)
public class Following {
    @Id
    RegisteredUser follower;
    @Id
    RegisteredUser followed;
}

public class FollowingId implements Serializable {
    private int follower;
    private int followed;
}
```

the types within the followingId class must match the type of the RegisteredUser Id. There are plenty of more complex examples if you search on JPA derived ID.

For queries, it depends on what you are looking for.  A collection of followers for a particular user could be obtained using JPQL:

```
"Select f.follower from Following f where f.followed = :user"
```

Comment: I get an error saying `'Id' attribute type should not be 'Persistence Entity'`

Comment: Update: The error mysteriously went away. Idk why I was getting it and what I did to fix it. But accepting this answer now. Thank you!